# Add target blank to link if is .pdf - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, pdf

My links looked like:

```
<a href="xxx.pdf">linktext</a>
```

I want to add some html to the a tag if there is a .pdf.

I've found this:

```
jQuery('a[href$=".pdf"]').each(function() {
    ....
});
```

But I dont know what I have to add to get this:

```
<a href="xxx.pdf" target="_blank" class="download">linktext</a>
```

Comment: class is done ... 
`jQuery('.entry-content a[href$=".pdf"]').each(function() {
    jQuery("a").addClass("test");
});`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the attribute using `.attr()` method.

```js
jQuery('a[href$=".pdf"]').addClass('download').attr('target', '_blank')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="xxx.pdf">linktext</a>
```